# PHP image upload, how do i set file permissions

Tags: php, plupload

I'm uploading to a 777 permissions folder. The uploads work however the uploaded files have 664 permissions and an 'Owner' of 'nobody'.

**How can i change the following scipt to upload files as 777 and set an Owner ?**

---

*code comes from Plupload's upload.php file*

```
if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

            fclose($out);
            unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
} else {
    // Open temp file
    $out = fopen($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName, $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

        fclose($out);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you won't be able to change ownership of the files, as that'd be the user ID the webserver's running under. You can try, using [`chown()`](http://php.net/chown), though, Most likely you could only change group ownership (using [`chgrp()`](http://php.net/chgrp)). Changing permissions is done via [`chmod()`](http://php.net/chmod).